# Reverse of series with $a_{0}\neq0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse

Suppose the following series

$$y=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{x^{4}}{12}+O(x^{5}).$$

How to obtain the series reversion

$$x=A_{0}+A_{1}y+A_{2}y^{2}+A_{3}y^{3}+O(y^{4}),$$

when the series starts from $a_{0}\neq0$ and the reversed one from
$A_{0}\neq0$? Unfortunately, the classical approach based on a substitution

$$y=1+(A_{0}+A_{1}y+A_{2}y^{2}+A_{3}y^{3}+O(y^{4}))+\frac{1}{2}(A_{0}+A_{1}y+A_{2}y^{2}+A_{3}y^{3}+O(y^{4}))^{2}+...,$$

does not work because of impossibility of determine $A_{0}$. I am looking for a method that can be easily implemented without additional libraries in C++...

Thanks
for your help.

---

**Updated solution:**

Suppose the simplified version of the series 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x & = & A_{1}(y-1)+A_{2}(y-1)^{2}+O((y-1)^{3}),\\
y-1 & = & x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+O(x^{3}),
\end{eqnarray*}
then, after a substitution
\begin{eqnarray*}
y-1 & = & A_{1}(y-1)+A_{2}(y-1^{2})+\frac{1}{2}\left[A_{1}(y-1)+A_{2}(y-1^{2})\right]^{2},\\
y' & = & A_{1}y^{\prime}+A_{2}y^{\prime}y^{\prime}+\frac{1}{2}\left[A_{1}y^{\prime}+A_{2}y^{\prime}y^{\prime}\right]{}^{2},\\
 & = & A_{1}y^{\prime}+(\frac{1}{2}A_{1}^{2}+A_{2})y^{\prime}y^{\prime}+O(y^{\prime3}),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $y^{\prime}=y-1$. Then, $A_{1}=1$, and $\frac{1}{2}+A_{2}=0\Rightarrow A_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$,
and

$$x=(y-1)-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^{2}+O((y-1)^{3}).$$

Comment: Do you want to invert the series ? (in the "usual" way )\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&x+a_1 x^2+ a_2 x^3 +\cdots \\
f^{-1}(x) &=& x-a_1 x^2 +(2a_1^2 -a_2)x^3+ \cdots
\end{eqnarray*} Let $x=x'-A_0$ and $f(x)=y-1$ ... and rescale so $A_1=1$

Comment: Sorry, but that can't be serious. Why on earth would anybody expect an expansion around $y=0$, if there's no indication that value will ever be attained? For $x=0$, we have $y=1$, so it would make sense to ask if we can express $x$ as a power series in $y-1$ (and we can, easily).

Comment: @ Professor: because of the input of a function in some library :-). More seriously, for a general series with a0 which general form of the inverse do you recommend?

Comment: @ Donald: Thanks for your answer, but how to determine A0?

Comment: In general,  $A_0$ need not exists. e.g. take $y = e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$. Assume the function $y = f(x)$ does has roots (say $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m$) For each root, you can set $A_0$ to that and determine the rest of $A_k$. Please note that if you have $m$ roots, then you have $m$ different sequences $A_k$.

Comment: @ achille: And what about this form of inverse?  $x=A_{1}(y-1)+A_{2}(y-1)^{2}+A_{3}(y-1)^{3}+O(4)$

Comment: You wrote $(y-1^2)$ where you probably meant $(y-1)^2$ a few times.

Comment: Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art: thanks for the check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply series reversion, you need to have $A_0=0$ and off-shift it accordingly:

$$y(0)=1$$

So when $y=1$, we need $x=0$:

$$x(1)=0$$

$$x=A_1(y-1)+A_2(y-1)^2+A_3(y-1)^3+A_4(y-1)^4+\mathcal O((y-1)^5)$$

$$y-1=x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\frac1{12}x^4+\mathcal O(x^5)$$

And by standard approaches, one may derive

$$x=(y-1)-\frac12(y-1)^2+\frac13(y-1)^3-\frac{23}{24}(y-1)^4+\mathcal O((y-1)^5)$$

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art: Thanks for your answer, see the updated question, please. Is it correct?

Comment: Oops, left my little $A_4$ in there.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art: Thank you very much, and greetings to America.