# Series reversion with constant term

Tags: power-series

Suppose we have $y=k+ax+bx^2+cx^3...$ as an infinite series. In order to reverse this I have been taught that we can assume $y-k=z$

Let's suppose $x=Az+Bz^2+Cz^3...$ Where $A,B,C...$ are determined by their usual formulas. By substituting $y-k=z$ back we get $x=A(y-k)+B(y-k)^2+C(y-k)^3...$. Rearranging this we obtain $$x=(-Ak+Bk^2-Ck^3....)+y(A-2Bk+3Ck^2...)+y^2(B-3Ck...)$$
Now since each coefficient is an infinite series in itself and for many examples these series may diverge, how do we determine them?

Comment: May I suggest to not expand $(y-k)^n$ ?

Comment: Yup, even I thought of that seeing this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440923/reverse-of-series-with-a-0-neq0

Answer (score 2):

The terms are not an infinite series.

Suppose that we write
$$y=k+\sum_{n=1}^{p>5}a_i x^i$$ and we make a Taylor expansion of it up to $O(x^5)$. Now, for more clarity, let $t=\frac{y-k}{a_1}$ and making the series reversion, we should get
$$x=t-\frac{a_2 }{a_1}t^2+\frac{\left(2 a_2^2-a_1 a_3\right)
   }{a_1^2}t^3+\frac{\left(-5 a_2^3+5 a_1 a_3 a_2-a_1^2 a_4\right)
   }{a_1^3}t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$